# Drop previous pandas tables after merged into 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, memory-management, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes together and then delete the first one to create space in RAM.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col='False')
df2 = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col='False')
df3 = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col='False')
df4 = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col='False')


result = df1.merge(df2, on='column1', how='left', left_index='True', copy='False')

result2 = result.merge(df3, on='column1', how='left', left_index='True', copy='False')
```

Ideally what I would like to do after this is delete all of df1, df2, df3 and have the `result2` dataframe left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better NOT to produce unnecessary DFs:

```
file_list = glob.glob('/path/to/file_mask*.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(file_list[0], index_col='False')

for f in file_list[1:]:
    df = df.merge(pd.read_csv(f, index_col='False'), on='column1', how='left')
```

PS IMO you can't (at least shouldn't) mix up `on` and `left_index` parameters. Maybe you meant `right_on` and `left_index` - that would be OK

Comment: your solution above is clever, but I have to merge multiple dataframes time and time again.

Comment: this will not suffice because the merging columns are different, but I could use an if statement to get around that no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use *del*

```
del df1, df2, df3, df4
```

Comment: Say df1 is 1GB, df2 is 1GB, so join(df1, df2) will be 2GB. Net memory occupied will be 1 + 1 + 2  = 4GB. If my memory limit is 2GB, the join won't happen. Is there any way to free up memory along with the progress of the join?